# Security requirement for an R&D team

Tags: audit

I have an R&D team that has been recently set up. I have been asked to help out with the cyber-security requirements for the department. They require access to anything and everything available on the internet, and also will require access to mailing sites other than O365. Any leads on what can be the different aspects I should make sure is available in my infrastructure to make this secure.
For example
Endpoints: I should implement DLPs to avoid the team from sharing confidential documents
Anti-virus (But will it be sufficient for zero day attacks)

Network point of view: I must segregate the team from rest of the organisation so I can customise policies specifically for this team...

Am I heading in the correct direction? What else should I be taking care of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a critical environment where you are introducing new devices which will be conforming to new, looser rules, it might be worth having an entirely different network 'air-gapped' - i.e. these new devices being completely separated from your existing infrastructure.  Many of the measures you take, such as a firewall, anti-virus, and group policies, will be the same as for existing computers.  The Internet itself is not scary, and having access to it does not mean immediate infection, but it will increase your potential attack surface.  You said restrictions need to be looser, but that does not mean they have to be lifted completely:

- Users probably don't need to install programs (if they do, you could do this manually as an admin, infrequently)
- Users probably don't need external mail (you said they do, but I see no reason why they would need e.g. GMail?)
- Users shouldn't have admin access to their computer
- etc.

It may however be worth getting a professional in to evaluate your systems and use case, where you act as project lead.  The contract for that will likely be considerably cheaper than the potential cost of infiltration.